# JavaScript replace is replacing every space for non-space

Tags: javascript, replace

I have a string with some pattern that I want to replace,

But somehow the result string is wrong, I don't know what's going on.

I tried it on console, and works as expected, but the current string that I want to replace, that comes from a JSON result does this:

```
var json = {str: 'Hi this _pattern_ will be replaced.'};
json.str = json.str.replace('_pattern_', 'pattern');
```

I'm expect as result:

```
'Hi this pattern will be replaced.'
```

But, I have this as result when I use the JSON that comes from the server:

```
'Hi thispatternwill be replaced.'
```

Why?

EDIT:

Heres an example of JSON that comes from the server, and the result is the same as I said:

```
{"MsgPreenchaCamposObrigatorios":"O campo _nomeCampo_ é de preenchimento obrigatório"}
```

Replacing `_nomeCampo_` trims every white space.

EDIT 2:

Here's the code that makes the replace:

```
var campo = 'Produto';
resources.MsgPreenchaCamposObrigatorios = resources.MsgPreenchaCamposObrigatorios.replace('_nomeCampo_', campo);
```

Comment: Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/PWe7e/ -- Is that the EXACT JSON that comes back from the server?

Comment: Maybe there aren't spaces in what the server sends you.

Comment: Works on the Firefox console.

Comment: I think you can get what you want by this `json.str = json.str.replace('_pattern_', ' pattern ');`.

Comment: it should work (tried in chrome console). wut browser are u using?

Comment: Are you replacing the exact string `_pattern_` or is that just a placeholder for an actual pattern?  If so, what is the real pattern you are replacing?

Comment: @X-Pippes, thats exacty what I'm doing, but the result string has no spaces between the replaced word

Comment: I put a blackslash before `_pattern_` .. the comment cut it out ;)
possible this assumes _ as regex or something, not _ char
try `\_pattern_`

Comment: Show us the actual code that does the replacement, without the simplification.

Comment: @CharlieKilian the code is in EDIT 2 as you want!

Comment: you tried `replace('\_pattern\_', 'pattern');` ?

Comment: @Fals - I can find nothing wrong with your code http://jsfiddle.net/F9zUT/ .. Do you have anything in your watch expressions which would manipulate your string?

Comment: Do you have any code/library that overwrites the `replace` method on the String object?

Comment: @Steve I'm using AngularJS, I did't found anything in my project that overrides the deffault method!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all, as @Krishna suggested, I checked out all $watch's and I found one that was messing up with the string when Its passed to a modal.